# C++ IPC Communication

Tags: c++, tcp, ip, ipc

I am in dilema to make decision on the below scenarios. Kindly need experts help.

Scenario :  There is TCP/IP communication between two process running in two boxes.

**Communication Method 1 :** Stream based communication on the socket. Where on the receiver side , he will receive the entire byte buffer and interpret first few fixed bytes as header and desrialize it and get to know the message length and start take message of that length and deserialize it and proceed to next message header like that goes on....

**Communication Method2 :** Put all the messages in a vector and vector will be residing in a class object. serialize the class object in one go and send to receiver. Receiver deserialize the class object and read the vector array one by one.

Please let me know which approach is efficient and if any other approach , please guide me.

Also pros and cons of class based data transmission and structure based data transmission and which is suitable for which scenario ?

Comment: I don't see a difference between the two methods. For the second method, the sender have to serialize the vector, send it to the receiver (probably over a streaming socket), and the receiver deserializes the received data into a vector. How is this different than the first method?

Comment: Which i mean here is 1. Single byte buffer contains 10 structures serialized and send to client. 2. Single byte buffer contains one object holding 10 strctures. And serializing one object and send to client.  If we do so ,  on the receiver side one deserialization is suffient. In the method(1) , we have deserialize number of times. Have you get it ?

Comment: The vector in the holding object in case two still has to be serialized/deserialized.

Comment: So you mean to say , the each item residing inside vector still needs to be serialized explicitly ?  or if we serialize vector , internally all the inside objects will be serialized ?

Comment: C++ doesn't have any built-in serialization. So yes, if you want to serialize an object, you have t do it explcitly

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question lacks some key details, and mixes different concerns, frustrating any attempt to provide a good answer.

Specifically, Method 2 mysteriously "serialises" and "deserialises" the object and contained vector without specifying any details of how that's being done.  In practice, the details are of the kind alluded to in Method 1.  So, 1 and 2 aren't alternatives unless you're choosing between using a serialisation library and doing it from scratch (in which case I'd say use the library as you're new to this and the library's more likely to get it right).

What I can say:

- at a TCP level, it's most efficient to read into a decent sized block (given I tend to work on PC/server hardware, I'd just use 64k though smaller may be enough to get the same kind of throughput) and have each `read()` or `recv()` read as much data from the socket as possible

  - after reading enough bytes (in however many read/recvs) to attempt some interpretation of the data, it's necessary to recognise the end of particular parts of the serialised input: sometimes that's implicit in the data type involved, other times it's communicated using some sentinel (e.g. a linefeed or NUL), and other times there can be a prefixed fixed-size "expect N bytes" header.  This aspect/consideration often applies hierarchically to the stream of objects and nested sub objects etc..
  - the TCP read/recvs may deliver more data than were sent in any single request, so you may have 1 or more bytes that are logically part of the subsequent but incomplete logical message at the end of the block assembled above
  - the process of reading larger blocks then accessing various fixed and variable sized elements inside the buffers is already supported by C++ iostreams, but you can roll your own if you want

So, let me emphasise this: do NOT assume you will receive any more than 1 byte from any given read of the socket: if you have say a 20 byte header you should loop reading until you hit either an error or have assembled all 20 bytes.  Sending 20 bytes in a single `write()` or `send()` does not mean the 20 bytes will be presented to a single `read()` / `recv()`.  TCP is a byte stream protocol, and you have to take arbitrary numbers of bytes as and when they're provided, waiting until you have enough data to interpret it.  Similarly, be prepared to get more data than the client could write in a single `write()`/`send().

> Also pros and cons of class based data transmission and structure based data transmission and which is suitable for which scenario ?

These terms are completely bogus.  classes and structures are almost identical things in C++ - mechanisms for grouping data and related functions (they differ only in how they - by default - expose the base classes and data members to client code).  Either can have or not have member functions or support code that helps serialise and deserialise the data.  For example, the simplest and most typical support are `operator<<` and/or `operator>>` streaming functions.

If you want to contrast these kind of streaming functions with an ad-hoc "write a binary block, read a binary block" approach (perhaps from thinking of structs as being POD without support code), then I'd say prefer streaming functions where possible, starting with streaming to human-readable representations as they'll make your system easier and quicker to develop, debug and support.  Once you're really comfortable with that, if the runtime performance requires it then optimise with a binary representation.  If you write the serialisation code well, you won't notice much difference in performance between a cruder `void*/#bytes` model of data and proper per-member serialisation, but the latter can more easily support unusual cases - portability across systems with different size ints/longs etc., different byte ordering, intentional choices re shallow vs. deep copying of pointed to data etc....

I'd also recommend looking at the boost serialisation library.  Even if you don't use it, it should give you a better understanding of how this kind of thing is reasonably implemented in C++.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are equivalent. In both you must send a header with message size and identifier in order to deserialize. If you assume that first option is composed by a serialized 'class' like a normal message, you must implement the same 'code'.

Another thing you must have in mind is message's size in order to full TCP buffers to optimize communications. If your 1st method messages are so little, try to improve the communication ratio with bigger messages like in 2nd option you describe.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that it's *not* safe simply streaming out a struct or class directly by interpreting it as a sequence of bytes, even if it's a simple POD - there's issues like endianness (which is unlikely to be a real-world problem for most of us), and structure alignment/padding (which *is* a potential problem).

C++ doesn't have any built-in serialization/deserialization, you'll either have to roll your own or take a look at things like [boost Serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), or Google's [protobuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/).

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a homework or study project, there may be little point in fiddling with IPC at TCP stream level especially if that's not something one is familiar with.

Use a messaging library, like [ØMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/intro%3aread-the-manual) to send and receive complete messages rather than streams of bytes.